# Pytest: resolving modules not found

Tags: python, directory, path, pytest

```
This is my folder structure:

project
  src
    -file1.py
    -file2.py
  tests
    -test_file.py

#file1.py
import file2
modules = 'module1' + file2.module2

#file2.py
module2 = 'module2'

#test_file.py
from ..src.file1 import modules
print(modules)
```

When I run pytest at project scope, I will get an error stating no module named file2. How can I resolve this error?